# How to use a sort of a "for" inside a view as in a template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to know how to use something like a `for`, like I do in a template, inside this function (in my view file):

```
def current_page(conn, data) do
  case conn.request_path do
    "/" -> "Home"
    for i <- data do
      i.link -> i.text
    end
    _ -> "Upps, not found!"
  end
end
```

I pass my `data` in my template:

```
<%= render FabricaASA.PageView, "head.html", conn: @conn, 
    data: [
            %{link: "/main", text: "Main"},
            %{link: "/home", text: "Home"},
          ]
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this data structure, you can do:

```
def current_page(conn, data) do
  cond do
    conn.request_path == "/" -> "Home"
    datum = Enum.find(data, &(&1.link == conn.request_path)) -> datum.text
    true -> "Upps, not found!"
  end
end
```

But this won't be as efficient as a pattern matching or map lookup based solution would have been. It's fine if you have just a few links, but I would suggest this which will both be faster and more readable in my opinion:

```
data: %{"/main" => "Main", "/home" => "Home"}
```

and then:

```
def current_page(conn, data) do
  cond do
    conn.request_path == "/" -> "Home"
    text = data[conn.request_path] -> text
    true -> "Upps, not found!"
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm going for the second version and it works fine (except that instead of `_` we need to have `true` (I got an error telling me that :) ). I must confess that this line `text = data[conn.request_path] -> text` is very confusing to me. Could you please point me some resources I could read or explain that a little bit further so that it is not just "magic" to me? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the `_`. So, `text = anything` in Elixir will set `text` to the value of `anything` and also return that value. `cond` will return the value on the right of `->` only if the left is truthy (not `nil` or `false`). So in this case, if `data[conn.request_path]` is neither `nil` nor `false`, `cond` will return that value, otherwise it'll skip to the next clause. Let me know if you still don't understand something!

Comment: I see! It has nothing to do with looping like I was expecting in my mind. Pattern matching avoids cycles because it only returns "the cond" that is matched so we don't need several lines of code...Thanks again!